# How to calculate median value for multiple geodata in one row/ cell/ unit

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, geospatial, median

These values are one(1) key-value pair. 
POLYGON consist of geodata pairs (epsg.io). I want to replace the long list of pairs with the median value.
**How can I calculate the median?**

```
stand_wkts_17518235_wkt': 'POLYGON ((492828.736516854 6954026.18089914,492829.429213483 6954026.56685419,492834.140449438 6954029.20224745,492808.438764045 6954067.00000026,492799.932022472 6954079.51011262,492785.838202247 6954073.80786543,492783.0 6954072.65955082,492733.313483146 6954052.55618004,492721.924157303 6954047.94831487,492688.998876405 6954034.62640475,492672.62752809 6954028.00280925,492654.375842697 6954020.61797779,492651.596067416 6954019.49325869,492651.734269663 6954019.11123622,492652.453932584 6954017.24606768,492653.392134832 6954015.48426992,492654.633146067 6954013.91292161,492655.988202247 6954012.44213509))
```

Comment: Try to see np.median docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html. If your problem instead is that you can't turn your data into a numpy-readable format, I suggest you change your question by adding a clearer and better formatted example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what data types you are working to start with, but if you are able to get your pairs into a string, it is pretty straight-forward.

```
pairs = '492828.736516854 6954026.18089914,492829.429213483 6954026.56685419,492834.140449438 6954029.20224745,492808.438764045 6954067.00000026,492799.932022472 6954079.51011262,492785.838202247 6954073.80786543,492783.0 6954072.65955082,492733.313483146 6954052.55618004,492721.924157303 6954047.94831487,492688.998876405 6954034.62640475,492672.62752809 6954028.00280925,492654.375842697 6954020.61797779,492651.596067416 6954019.49325869,492651.734269663 6954019.11123622,492652.453932584 6954017.24606768,492653.392134832 6954015.48426992,492654.633146067 6954013.91292161,492655.988202247 6954012.44213509'
```

Use split

```
pair_lst = [pair.split() for pair in pairs.split(',')]
```

Convert strings back to float and make a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[float(pair[0]) for pair in pair_lst],[float(pair[1]) for pair in pair_lst]]).T
```

Calculate median of the columns with:

```
df[0].median()
df[1].median()
```

This can probably be done much more efficiently/succinctly, but I figured I would give it a shot.

Comment: Could you please up-vote if this solution is useful to you?